# c++ program doesn't print and breaks down

Tags: c++

my program doesn't print anything . What is wrong ? It's breaking down after compiling
I tried without void functions and it was Ok but i have to use a function.

```
    #define N 8
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void put(int table[N][N],int a,int b)
{
int x;
  x=a;
   for(int y=b;y<8;y++)
   {
       table[x][y]=1;
       x++;
    }
x=a;

    for(int y=b;y>=0;y--)
    {
       table[x][y]=1;
        x++;
     }
x=a;
   for(int y=b;y>=0;y--)
    {
     table[x][y]=1;
    x--;
     }

 x=a;

     for(int y=b;y<8;y++)
   {
       table[x][y]=1;
       x--;
    }

table[a][b]=2;
}

int main()
{
    int table[N][N] = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, };

put(table,2,2);

for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            cout<<table[i][j]<<" ";

        }
       cout<<endl;
      }
    return 0;
}
```

It has to place bishop on chess board and occupy cells. So I wrote 'put' function but something doesnt work here

Comment: You are going out of the array bound in the last for loop. You start with `x=2 y=2`, next loop is `x=1 y=3`, next `x=0 y=4` and next `x=-1 y=5`. Oops!

Comment: put(table,2,2) so x=a=2; Program puts bishop on 2;2 position and occupies diagonal cells with '1'

Comment: strange thing is , what everything works when I have no function void

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behaviour in your last for loop, as `x` becomes `-1`.

You could simplify the `put` function considerably like this:

```
void put(int table[N][N],int a,int b)
{
   for(int y = 0; y < 8; ++y)
   {
       table[a][y] = 1;
       table[y][b] = 1;
   }

   table[a][b]=2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you , but It has to occupy diagonally ,